# Why is Java's Iterator not an Iterable?

Tags: java, iterator, iterable

Why does the `Iterator` interface not extend `Iterable`?

The `iterator()` method could simply return `this`.

Is it on purpose or just an oversight of Java's designers?

It would be convenient to be able to use a for-each loop with iterators like this:

```
for(Object o : someContainer.listSomeObjects()) {
    ....
}
```

where `listSomeObjects()` returns an iterator.

Comment: OK - I see your point buut . it would still be convenient even if it broke a semantics a little :]

Thank U for all the answers :]

Comment: I realize this question was asked long ago, but - do you mean any Iterator, or just an Iterator relating to some Collection?

Comment: Just FYI, several years after this question, JavaScript got the concepts of "iterable" and "iterator" (though being JavaScript, a bit different from Java's). All of the iterators you get from the standard JavaScript library ... are also iterable, because they implement the relevant method with `return this`. :-)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Because an iterator generally points to a single instance in a collection. Iterable implies that one may obtain an iterator from an object to traverse over its elements - and there's no need to iterate over a single instance, which is what an iterator represents.

Comment: +1: A collection is iterable.  An iterator is not iterable because it's not a collection.

Comment: While I agree with the answer, I don't know if I agree with the mentality.  The Iterable interface presents a single method: Iterator<?> iterator();  In whatever case, I should be able to specify an iterator to for-each. I don't buy it.

Comment: @S.Lott nice circular reasoning there.

Comment: @Zefi: Iterator != Iterable.  Doesn't seem circular at all.  It's a matter of definition.  While it's not defined that way in Python, it is defined that way in Java.

Comment: @S.Lott you said: Collection is iterable; Iterator is not iterable because it is not a collection.  If you don't know, that's what we call circular reasoning.  It's like saying: I'm awesome.  You're not me so you're not awesome.

Comment: @Zefi: I can't see the circularity yet.  Merely repeating the words isn't helping.  "Iterator" has a definition; it is not itself iterable, but works with iterable objects.  "Iterable" has a definition.  It is not an iterator, but works with iterators.  Since "iterator" and "iterable" are not the same thing -- they are not defined using "is-a" -- I can't see the circularity.  You're going to have to provide more detail to explain how two different but related concepts are "circular".

Comment: @S.Lott Last attempt: Collection ∈ Iterable.  Iterator ≠ Collection ∴ Iterator ∉ Iterable

Comment: @S.Lott your comment should be an independent answer. It's great; simply the definition.

Comment: @S.Lott: Collection is totally irrelevant to this discussion. Collection is just one of many possible implementations of Iterable. The fact that something is not a Collection has no bearing on whether it is an Iterable.

Comment: @Zefi: your "awesome" example does match S. Lott's method of arguing in his initial comment, but neither one of them is circular reasoning. I agree somewhat with ColinD that the "Collection" aspect is a bit of a red herring, though it makes some sense in light of "an iterator *generally* points to a single instance in a collection."

Comment: The answer is an attempt to rationalize the bad, antihuman design. Iterable intuitively and usefully means the thing you can iterate over. There is not need to argument for collection or any other shit. Otherwise, if you like, the iterator is a collection also and you can iterate over it.

Comment: @S.Lott "An iterator is not iterable because it's not a collection"? What are you smoking? Iterators are not built for collections.

Comment: An Iterator is something that abstract the iteration. So, it's an ACTIVE actor. An iterable is something that can be iterated on, it's a PASSIVE subject. So, that's why one can ask an Iterable to have an iterator. This is not "antihuman" design, by separating the two, one can ask many iterators and use them independently. That's because people are looking at them trough a "foreach" lens that they find it odd. (4 years late to the party, I know)

Comment: "Why does the Iterator interface not extend Iterable?" was the original question. It is not asking how Java defines things, but why.

Answer (score 226):

An iterator is stateful. The idea is that if you call `Iterable.iterator()` twice you'll get *independent* iterators - for most iterables, anyway. That clearly wouldn't be the case in your scenario.

For example, I can usually write:

```
public void iterateOver(Iterable<String> strings)
{
    for (String x : strings)
    {
         System.out.println(x);
    }
    for (String x : strings)
    {
         System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

That should print the collection twice - but with your scheme the second loop would always terminate instantly.

Comment: It's entirely implementation dependent whether you'll get independent iterators.  You have no way of ensuring they are.

Comment: @Chris: If an implementation returns the same iterator twice, how on earth could it fulfil the contract of Iterator? If you call `iterator` and use the result, it has to iterate over the collection - which it won't do if that same object has already iterated over the collection. Can you give *any* correct implementation (other than for an empty collection) where the same iterator is returned twice?

Comment: This is a great response Jon, you've really got the crux of the problem here. Shame this isn't the accepted answer!

The contract for Iterable is strictly defined, but the above is a great explanation of the reasons why allowing Iterator to implement Iterable (for foreach) would break the spirit of the interface.

Comment: @JonSkeet while an Iterator<T> is stateful, the contract of Iterable<T> says nothing about being able to be used twice to get independent iterators, even tho it is the scenario in 99% cases.
All Iterable<T> says is that it allows an object to be the target of foreach.

For those of you who are unhappy with Iterator<T> not being an Iterable<T>, you are free to make such an Iterator<T>. It wouldn't break the contract one bit.

However - Iterator itself should not be Iterable since that would make it circularly dependent and that lays the ground for icky design.

Comment: @Centril: Right. Have edited to indicate that *usually* calling `iterable` twice will give you independent iterators.

Comment: This does get to the heart of it. It would almost be possible to implement an Iterable Iterator that implements .iterator() by resetting itself, but this design would still break in some circumstances, for example, if it was passed to a method that takes an Iterable and loops over all possible pairs of elements by nesting for-each loops.

Comment: While I am quite late to the game here, this should be Community Wiki and the Accepted Answer. It correctly identifies WHY a Iterator can never be Iterable. And it's all down to the State it carries.

Comment: @AndrewTFinnell Out of interest, why do you think it should be Community Wiki?

Comment: I don't see why having *iterators* implement `Iterable` by returning `this` would make the code in the answer fail to output the collection twice. The code in the question calls `iterator()` on `strings` (an `Iterable`) twice, not on an iterator. JavaScript's iterators actually do implement iterable (the built-in ones do anyway, you can write one that doesn't), and in exactly the way the OP suggested: They just return `this`. It's handy for skipping the first couple of entries (for instance) before going into a `for-of` loop (JavaScript's version of the enhanced `for`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I agree, it calls `iterator()` twice... but when that returns a reference to the same object twice, how can the two iterators be independent? Or are you suggesting it's fine for the `iterator()` method to basically behave completely differently based on whether it's called on a "normal" `Iterable` or an "`Iterator` that also implements `Iterable`"? That doesn't sound like a good idea to me. My `iterateOver` method should be able to work with any `Iterable`... which means each `iterator()` call creating an independent iterator.

Comment: @JonSkeet - The latter. `Iterable.iterator` would always return a new object as it does now (needs the state you mention), but `Iterator.iterator` would return `this`. So calling `iterator` on `strings` (the `Iterable`) returns a new `Iterator` each time you call it. But if you call `iterator` on that `Iterator`, it returns `this`. Which makes it compatible with the enhanced `for` loop. Here's the equivalent JavaScript situation: https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/kf19vpam/ It works really well in JS-land. I take your point about it being different behavior, but it's quite handy...

Comment: ...and classes *already* decide what they mean by being iterable. Another approach to it would be to make it return a new iterator starting where it is in the sequence (a clone). I wasn't involved in the discussions where they added the current behavior so don't know if they considered doing that. (Discussions of that type are much better documented now than they were before the 2015 spec.)

Comment: (I say this as someone who in 2012 responded to a version of this question -- I didn't realize it was a dupe -- with "That doesn't make any sense." :-D And then I made the semantics argument.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: But there isn't an `Iterator.iterator()` method, and I don't *think* Java has the ability to implement the same method name differently for different interfaces. (That may have changed - it's been a while since I wrote Java in earnest). I think if we're proposing new methods, it would make more sense for the enhanced for loop to just work with `Iterator` without calling an `iterator()` method at all.

Comment: @JonSkeet - `Iterable` and `Iterator` are just interfaces, the implementations would be on (say) `SomeList` and the usually-private class that implements `SomeList`'s `Iterator`. Re the enhanced `for` loop: Agreed, I've always wondered why it didn't. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: But this question is suggesting that `Iterator` should extend `Iterable`. If you pass some iterator into my `iterateOver` method (as an iterable), that *should* print the sequence twice... the two calls should return independent iterators IMO... otherwise it's really making the behavior of `Iterable` very hard to predict. I would suggest we call a halt here though... we may well be talking part each other, and Stack Overflow comment threads really aren't the best forum for this.

Comment: Well, I think it's probably worth considering some flexibility around that "should." Again, classes (in this case, the iterator class for a collection) define what it means to be `Iterable` for them. The equiv,. of your fn above loops through once if given an iterable that's an iterator in JavaScript. But mostly I was just bothered that people didn't seem to get the OP's idea (**I** originally dismissed this sort of idea as silly without really thinking about it), but has fundamentally been embraced in another -- very large -- arena. :-) Anyway, hope all is well and the drumming's still fun! –

Comment: For everyone reading this, in Python, iterators return themselves when you request an interator. So `iter(iterator) is iterator` *should always be true* if the protocol is followed correctly

Answer (score 65):

For my $0.02, I completely agree that Iterator should not implement Iterable, but I think the enhanced for loop should accept either. I think the whole "make iterators iterable" argument comes up as a work around to a defect in the language.

The whole reason for the introduction of the enhanced for loop was that it "eliminates the drudgery and error-proneness of iterators and index variables when iterating over collections and arrays" [[1](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html#forloop)].

```
Collection<Item> items...

for (Iterator<Item> iter = items.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Item item = iter.next();
    ...
}

for (Item item : items) {
    ...
}
```

Why then does this same argument not hold for iterators?

```
Iterator<Iter> iter...
..
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Item item = iter.next();
    ...
}

for (Item item : iter) {
    ...
}
```

In both cases, the calls to hasNext() and next() have been removed, and there is no reference to the iterator in the inner loop. Yes, I understand that Iterables can be re-used to create multiple iterators, but that all happens outside of the for loop: inside the loop there is only ever a forward progression one item at a time over the items returned by the iterator.

Also, allowing this would also make it easy to use the for loop for Enumerations, which, as has been pointed out elsewhere, are analogous to Iterators not Iterables.

So don't make Iterator implement Iterable, but update the for loop to accept either.

Cheers,

Comment: I agree. Theoretically there could be confusion when getting an iterator, using part of it, and then putting it in a foreach (breaking the "each" contract of foreach), but I don't think that's a good enough reason not to have this feature.

Comment: We already have updated/enhanced the loop to accept arrays instead of making arrays iterable collection. Can you rationalize this decision?

Comment: I upvoted this reply, and it was a mistake. Iterator is stateful, if you promote iteration over an iterator with the `for(item : iter) {...}` syntax, then it will provoke an error when the same iterator is iterated twice. Imagine that `Iterator` is passed into `iterateOver` method instead of `Iterable` in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/839195/1060693).

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether you use the `for (String x : strings) {...}` or `while (strings.hasNext()) {...}` style: if you try to loop through an iterator twice the second time will yield no results, so I don't see that in itself as an argument against allowing the enhanced syntax. Jon's answer is different, because there he's showing how wrapping an `Iterator` in an `Iterable` would cause problems, as in that case you would expect to be able to reuse it as many times as you liked.

Answer (score 19):

As pointed out by others, [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) are two different things.

Also, `Iterator` implementations predate enhanced for loops.

It is also trivial to overcome this limitation with a simple adapter method that looks like this when used with static method imports:

```
for (String line : in(lines)) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Sample implementation:

```
  /**
   * Adapts an {@link Iterator} to an {@link Iterable} for use in enhanced for
   * loops. If {@link Iterable#iterator()} is invoked more than once, an
   * {@link IllegalStateException} is thrown.
   */
  public static <T> Iterable<T> in(final Iterator<T> iterator) {
    assert iterator != null;
    class SingleUseIterable implements Iterable<T> {
      private boolean used = false;

      @Override
      public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        if (used) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("SingleUseIterable already invoked");
        }
        used = true;
        return iterator;
      }
    }
    return new SingleUseIterable();
  }
```

---

In Java 8 adapting an `Iterator` to an `Iterable` gets simpler:

```
for (String s : (Iterable<String>) () -> iterator) {
```

Comment: you declared a class in a function; am i missing something? i thought this was illegal.

Comment: A class can be defined in a block in Java.  It's called a [local class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html)

Comment: Thanks for the `for (String s : (Iterable<String>) () -> iterator)`

Answer (score 9):

Incredibly, no one else has given this answer yet. Here's how you can "easily" iterate over an `Iterator` by using the new Java 8 [`Iterator.forEachRemaining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#forEachRemaining-java.util.function.Consumer-) method:

```
Iterator<String> it = ...
it.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
```

Of course, there's a "simpler" solution that works with the foreach loop directly, wrapping the `Iterator` in an `Iterable` lambda:

```
for (String s : (Iterable<String>) () -> it)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: I think no-one gave this answer earlier, because Java 8 was not out yet when this question was originally asked.

Comment: @KarstenSpang: Yes, but when I gave it, Java 8 has been out for a while...

Answer (score 8):

As others have said, an Iterable can be called multiple times, returning a fresh Iterator on each call; an Iterator is used just once.  So they are related, but serve different purposes.  Frustratingly, however, the "compact for" method works only with an iterable.

What I will describe below is one way to have the best of both worlds - returning an Iterable (for nicer syntax) even when the underlying sequence of data is one-off.

The trick is to return an anonymous implementation of the Iterable that actually triggers the work.  So instead of doing the work that generates a one-off sequence and then returning an Iterator over that, you return an Iterable which, each time it is accessed, redoes the work.  That might seem wasteful, but often you will only call the Iterable once anyway, and even if you do call it multiple times, it still has reasonable semantics (unlike a simple wrapper that makes an Iterator "look like" an Iterable, this won't fail if used twice).

For example, say I have a DAO that provides a series of objects from a database, and I want to provide access to that via an iterator (eg. to avoid creating all objects in memory if they are not needed).  Now I could just return an iterator, but that makes using the returned value in a loop ugly.  So instead I wrap everything in an anon Iterable:

```
class MetricDao {
    ...
    /**
     * @return All known metrics.
     */
    public final Iterable<Metric> loadAll() {
        return new Iterable<Metric>() {
            @Override
            public Iterator<Metric> iterator() {
                return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                        .createQuery("from Metric as metric")
                        .iterate();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

this can then be used in code like this:

```
class DaoUser {
    private MetricDao dao;
    for (Metric existing : dao.loadAll()) {
        // do stuff here...
    }
}
```

which lets me use the compact for loop while still keeping incremental memory use.

This approach is "lazy" - the work is not done when the Iterable is requested, but only later when the contents are iterated over - and you need to be aware of the consequences of that.  In the example with a DAO that means iterating over the results within the database transaction.

So there are various caveats, but this can still be a useful idiom in many cases.

Comment: nice ans but your `returning a fresh Iterator on each call` should be accompanied with **why** i.e to prevent concurrency issue...

Answer (score 7):

`Iterator` is an interface which allows you to iterate over something. It is an implementation of moving through a collection of some kind.

`Iterable` is a functional interface which denotes that something contains an accessible iterator.

In Java8, this makes life pretty easy... If you have an `Iterator` but need an `Iterable` you can simply do:

```
Iterator<T> someIterator;
Iterable<T> = ()->someIterator;
```

This also works in the for-loop:

```
for (T item : ()->someIterator){
    //doSomething with item
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## To avoid dependence on `java.util` package

According to the original JSR, [*An enhanced for loop for the Java™ Programming Language*](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/jsr/tiger/enhanced-for.html), the proposed interfaces:

- [`java.lang.Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html)
- `java.lang.ReadOnlyIterator`
  (proposed to be retrofitted onto `java.util.Iterator`, but apparently this never happened)

…were designed to use the `java.lang` package namespace rather than `java.util`.

To quote the JSR:

> These new interfaces serve to prevent the dependency of the language on java.util that would otherwise result.

---

By the way, the old `java.util.Iterable` gained a new [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) method in Java 8+, for use with lambda syntax (passing a [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html)).

Here is an example. The [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) interface extends [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface, as any list carries a `forEach` method.

```
List
.of ( "dog" , "cat" , "bird" )
.forEach ( ( String animal ) -> System.out.println ( "animal = " + animal ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

I also see many doing this:

```
public Iterator iterator() {
    return this;
}
```

But that does not make it right!
This method would not be what you want!

The method `iterator()` is supposed to return a new iterator starting from scratch.
So one need to do something like this:

```
public class IterableIterator implements Iterator, Iterable {

  //Constructor
  IterableIterator(SomeType initdata)
  {
    this.initdata = iter.initdata;
  }
  // methods of Iterable

  public Iterator iterator() {
    return new IterableIterator(this.intidata);
  }

  // methods of Iterator

  public boolean hasNext() {
    // ...
  }

  public Object next() {
    // ...
  }

  public void remove() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The question is: would there be any way to make an abstract class performing this?
So that to get an IterableIterator one only need to implement the two methods next() and hasNext()

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the accepted answer, but want to add my own explanation.

- Iterator represents the state of traversing, e.g., you can get the current element from an iterator and move forward to the next.
- Iterable represents a collection which could be traversed, it can return as many iterators as you want, each representing its own state of traversing, one iterator may be pointing to the first element, while another may be pointing to the 3rd element.

It would be nice if Java for loop accepts both Iterator and Iterable.

Answer (score 1):

On a related note, you may find the IteratorIterable adapter in Apache Commons Collections4 useful. Just create an instance from an iterator, and you have the corresponding iterable.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/iterators/IteratorIterable.html

ID: org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0

Answer (score 1):

If you came here in search of a workaround, you can use [IteratorIterable](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/iterators/IteratorIterable.html). (available for Java 1.6 and above)

Example usage (reversing a Vector).

```
import java.util.Vector;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.iterators.IteratorIterable;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.iterators.ReverseListIterator;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        Vector<String> vs = new Vector<String>();
        vs.add("one");
        vs.add("two");
        for ( String s: vs ) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        Iterable<String> is
            = new IteratorIterable(new ReverseListIterator(vs));
        for ( String s: is ) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
one
two
two
one
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, Iterator and Iterable are two distinct concepts, Iterable is simply a shorthand for "I can return an Iterator". I think that your code should be:

```
for(Object o : someContainer) {
}
```

with someContainer instanceof `SomeContainer extends Iterable<Object>`

Answer (score 0):

As an aside: Scala has a toIterable() method in Iterator. See [scala implicit or explicit conversion from iterator to iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2746814/scala-implicit-or-explicit-conversion-from-iterator-to-iterable)

Answer (score 0):

Iterators are stateful, they have a "next" element and become "exhausted" once iterated over. To see where the problem is, run the following code, how many numbers are printed?

```
Iterator<Integer> iterator = Arrays.asList(1,2,3).iterator();
Iterable<Integer> myIterable = ()->iterator;
for(Integer i : myIterable) System.out.print(i);
System.out.println();
for(Integer i : myIterable) System.out.print(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following example :

```
List ispresent=new ArrayList();
Iterator iterator=ispresent.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
{
    System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```