# Parse string to JSON

Tags: java, json, loops, parsing, iterator

I'm parsing this JSON string with the libs in org.json and I can't understand why I get the output below into the log.

```
ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONObject demo = new JSONObject("{\"00408C88A2E6\":{\"id\":\"00408C88A2E6\",\"name\":\"Lab\"},\"00408C91188B\":{\"id\":\"00408C91188B\",\"name\":\"Lab1\"},\"00408C944B99\":{\"id\":\"00408C944B99\",\"name\":\"Lato1\"},\"00408C944BA0\":{\"id\":\"00408C944BA0\",\"name\":\"Lato\"}}");
Iterator<String> iterator =  demo.keys();
while (iterator.hasNext() ){    
  al.add((String)iterator.next());
  Log.i(LOG_TAG, "size al into while " + al.size());
  Log.i(LOG_TAG, "MAC " + iterator.next() + " for the user " + userId);
}
```

Log output

```
07-12 08:55:34.056: INFO/parse(285): size al into while 1
07-12 08:55:34.056: INFO/parse(285): MAC 00408C91188B for the user nweb
07-12 08:55:34.066: INFO/parse(285): size al into while 2
07-12 08:55:34.066: INFO/parse(285): MAC 00408C944B99 for the user nweb
07-12 08:55:34.066: INFO/parse(285): size al 2
```

Should not have 4 elements in my ArrayList?
Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You called `iterator.next()` twice in the body of the loop. Each time you do, the iterator advances forward.

You may want to call it once in the body and store it in a local variable.

```
String next = iterator.next();
al.add(next);
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "MAC " + next + " for the user " + userId);
```

Note that `Iterator<E>` defines `E next()`, so you don't need the cast to `String` in this case.

---

#### Another illustrative example

Here's an example from [Java Language Guide/For-each loop](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html):

> Here is a common mistake people make when they are trying to do nested
>   iteration over two collections:
>
> ```
> List suits = ...;
> List ranks = ...;
> List sortedDeck = new ArrayList();
>
> // BROKEN - throws NoSuchElementException!
> for (Iterator i = suits.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
>     for (Iterator j = ranks.iterator(); j.hasNext(); )
>         sortedDeck.add(new Card(i.next(), j.next()));
> ```
>
> Can you spot the bug? Don't feel bad if you can't. Many expert programmers
>   have made this mistake at one time or another. The problem is that the `next`
>   method is being called too many times on the “outer” collection (suits). It
>   is being called in the inner loop for both the outer and inner collections,
>   which is wrong. In order to fix it, you have to add a variable in the
>   scope of the outer loop to hold the suit:
>
> ```
> // Fixed, though a bit ugly
> for (Iterator i = suits.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
>     Suit suit = (Suit) i.next();
>     for (Iterator j = ranks.iterator(); j.hasNext(); )
>         sortedDeck.add(new Card(suit, j.next()));
> }
> ```
>
> So what does all this have to do with the for-each construct? It is tailor-made for
>   nested iteration! Feast your eyes:
>
> ```
> for (Suit suit : suits)
>    for (Rank rank : ranks)
>        sortedDeck.add(new Card(suit, rank));
> ```

Had [`JSONObject.keys()`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#keys%28%29) been an `Iterable` instead of `Iterator`, then for-each is the best solution in your case. If you think the improvement in readability is worth it, you can e.g. add the `keys` into a `Collection<String>`, which is an `Iterable`.

#### Related questions

- [Why is Java’s Iterator not an Iterable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/839178/why-is-javas-iterator-not-an-iterable)
- [How does the Java for each loop work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)