# Copy an Iterator

Tags: java, reference, iterator

In java, how to copy iteators? Here since i, and j are reference variable change in one gets reflected in another. How to get the expected output of 1 1 in below code. Instead of 1 2.

```
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        l.add(1);
        l.add(2);
        l.add(3);
        l.add(4);

        Iterator i = l.iterator();
        Iterator j = i;

        System.out.println(i.next() + "\n");
        System.out.println(j.next()); 
        System.out.println("This prints 1 2, But I want 1 1, to be printed");
```

Edit:

I could do,

`Iterator i = l.iterator();
 Iterator j = l.iterator();`

 But getting this iterator is not as simple as in this example, it cost much. So I don't to do that in my original code.  Actually What I will get is a Iterator of DB Rows, it includes many complex criteria's.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to "copy" an `Iterator`, as it usually does not hold the content of the whole underlying collection (that's what iterators are about). You can however just create another one from your List, using `#iterator()`.

Comment: @qqilihq I don't agree. Think about a wide branching recursive algorithm where you don't want each sub-call to change the iterator you are working on and instead give them a copy of the iterator.

Comment: @Perseids Thats what I will do with pointers in linked list in C.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963399/how-can-i-make-a-copy-of-an-iterator-in-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3831912/java-why-are-iterators-not-copyable

Answer (score 3):

```
Iterator j = l.iterator();
```

instead of

```
Iterator j = i;
```

We can iterate only in one direction. So, without getting new iterator, you cannot move to the start of collection. Moreover, getting iterator doesn't mean you load entire collection. Think of it like a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to copy an iterator.

The reason is that the interface is meant to also support implementations where a simple copy of the state is not possible or difficult. For example imagine a wrapper around an input stream that iterates over the lines output by the input stream. If you would want to copy the iterator then you either would have to also copy the input stream (difficult or impossible if it is a socket for example) or cache all lines that the other instance of the iterator has already returned.

If you are lucky the iterator implementation returned by your library call actually supports copy operations, but that would have to be done in a non standard way.