# How can I generate a List backed by a Function?

Tags: java, list, functional-programming, guava

I have a function `myFunction` of `Function<Integer, T>`, and I want to construct an object `mylist` of size `size`, implementing `List<T>` (or maybe some kind of immutable list interface), backed by the function, in the sense that `mylist.get(i) == myFunction.apply(i)`.

I can do this manually, but is there some (Guava) code which does the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `java.util.AbstractList`:

```
 new AbstractList<T>() {
   public T get(int i) {
     Preconditions.checkElementIndex(i, size);
     return function.apply(i);
   }
   public int size() {
     return size;
   }
 }
```

The result would not necessarily be immutable, since the function output could vary.  In all likelihood, you could get rid of the `Function` entirely, and just write the implementation of the `Function` in your `AbstractList` implementation.

Comment: where is `size` coming from?

Comment: Wherever you want it to come from.  There's no such thing as a list without a size, so presumably the OP had a size coming from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of a list you should consider an `Iterator<T>`.

```
// Example simple Function that returns each element from the array.
static class Function<T> {
    final T[] t;
    Function(T[] t) {
        this.t = t;
    }
    T apply (Integer i) {
        return t[i];
    }
}

static class FunctionIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    final Function<T> f;
    Integer i;
    Integer to;
    Integer step;

    FunctionIterator(Function<T> f, Integer from, Integer to) {
        this.f = f;
        if ( to > from ) {
            step = 1;
            i = from;
            this.to = to;
        } else {
            step = -1;
            i = to;
            this.to = from;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return i != to + step;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        T next = f.apply(i);
        i += step;
        return next;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported.");
    }
}
```

This code offers an `Iterator`. You can make an `Iterable` from it quite easily. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8555153/823393) is an excellent and neat example of how to do it.