# Java Explicit iterator works. Implicit forloop yields "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable"

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator, abstract-class, iterable

I've implemented Iterable<> in my base class but the subclass will not allow an implicit forloop.

Why is the Iterator<> working correctly but the for-loop complaining of

```
Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
```

I would have expected the Iterable<> interface to be visible in the subclass. What am I missing?

```
package tester;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TestInher {

    private Concrete<Integer>   mList   = new Concrete<Integer>();

    public TestInher() {}

    public abstract class   Base<T>
        implements Iterable<T>
    {
        protected ArrayList<T>  list = new ArrayList<T>();

        @Override
        public Iterator<T> iterator() {return list.iterator();}

        public abstract void add(T item);
    }

    public abstract class   ClassAbstract<T> extends    Base<T>{}

    public class    Concrete<T>
        extends ClassAbstract<T>
    {
        @Override
        public void add(T item) {list.add(item);}
    }

    public void doIt() {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {mList.add(i);}

        Iterator<Integer> i = mList.iterator(); 
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(i.next());
        }

        //Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
        for(Integer i : mList.iterator()) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Iterator` is not `Iterable`.

Comment: Not a serious suggestion, but you could actually make your `Iterator` implement `Iterable` with an idempotent method `return this`. Then your code would actually work, even if meaninglessly so :)

Comment: I'm trying to remember the oddity, but I'm recalling that, at least in some circumstances, an interface is not implicitly inherited by subclasses -- if you intend the interface to be supported you must explicitly state that in the subclass definition.

Comment: Related: [Why is Java's Iterator not an Iterable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/839178/why-is-javas-iterator-not-an-iterable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [the enhanced `for` loop, you iterate over the `Iterable`](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html), not over the `Iterator`.  The `Iterable` gets the `Iterator` that is implicitly used in this loop, but an `Iterable` is not itself the `Iterator`.  Try the `Iterable` itself.

```
for (Integer i : mList) {
```

Comment: I get Iritable just thinking about it.

Comment: *sigh* I kept staring and never saw the typo. Thanks.